# Access to XMLHttpRequest (sound.mp3) has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, html, howler.js, tone.js

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at "./sounds/sound.mp3" from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

I am making a project where I want to make a game, but nothing major is a canvas element. (all moving IMG tags and divs)

OTHER SOLUTIONS DO NOT WORK. I am using howler.js to play a sound clip and I get this, however sometimes tone.js DOES work. I don't know how to fix this because I need non-tech savvy people to use this file, so chrome settings are off limits for me. Also, I can't use localhost or web servers. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: You cannot use a page loaded from file protocol to Ajax to a CORS enabled server

Comment: You will have to download the resources to the same file system as the page

Answer (score 0):

Run the entire website as localhost (using xampp for example) should fix it

Comment: Sorry, I can't use that. As I said, I cannot use a web-server to run it.

Comment: @SuperJumpBros  Then you are SOL

Comment: Don't know if there is another way. As for as I know you can solve CORS by hosting (localhost or website) or do the weird chrome settings thing

Comment: Darn! I thought I could fix this another way

Comment: Unfortunately I don't thing there is

Answer (score -2):

You can put this code in a batch script (Windows) or a shell script (Linux/Mac) and ask them to double click on the script (if they are using Google Chrome - I don't think you can do this on Firefox):

Windows:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe <path to file>`

Linux:

`google-chrome <path to file> -allow-file-access-from-files`

Mac:

`open -a 'Google Chrome' <path to file> —allow-file-access-from-files`